# Wordpress array for product and post on same page

Tags: php, wordpress

I use the array to show all products and posts on the same page:

```
$args = array( 
 'post_type' => array( 'product', 'post' ),
 'posts_per_page' => 999,
 'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', 
 'meta_key' => 'score_value',
 'order' => 'DESC'
);
 
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Now I want to filter posts `'cat' => '82,85'` and products `'product_cat' => 96`.

I have added the code snippes to my code, but after no post or products are shown.

```
$args = array( 
 'post_type' => array( 'product', 'post' ),
 'cat' => '82,85',
 'product_cat' => 96,
 'posts_per_page' => 999,
 'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num', 
 'meta_key' => 'score_value',
 'order' => 'DESC'
);
 
$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

How should I modify my code that both post types and all posts and products within the categories will be displayed?

Thank you,

Mags

Comment: You probably want `cat` to be an array, not a comma separated string:  `'cat' => [82, 85],`

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't solve my problem. I guess there must be somehow an OR connection between ```'cat'``` and ```'product_cat'```. It looks like that in my code it's an AND Connection and of course this will give a result "no content found". But I'm not so firm with php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using [tax_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_tax_query/).

```
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => array('product', 'post'),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'category',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => ['82', '85'],
        ),
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field'    => 'term_id',
            'terms'    => ['96'],
        ),
    ),
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'orderby'        => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'       => 'score_value',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args);
```